# Rebooting from Windows 11 to Kubuntu 21.10 causes mic issues

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows, microphone, 21.10

It's so weird that I have to shutdown Windows 11 to be able to use the internal laptop mic on Kubuntu. Restarting and then booting into Kubuntu completely disables the internal mic. Any explanations?

Comment: Is Fast Boot on (in Windows)? If so, turn it off. Fast Boot is very much not compatible with Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro that I know of).

Comment: When Windows does not do a clean shutdown, it can leave hardware in an "intermediate state". When other operating systems boot, they are unable to get a proper connection to the device, leading to functionality issues. As @cocomac suggests, disabling "Fast Boot" is generally an adequate way of solving this problem.

Comment: Fast boot is disabled.

Comment: Actually it's **Fast Startup** (Fast Boot is a UEFI feature). Make sure the **Windows** Fast Startup feature is disabled, it's a must when dual-booting, precisely because of situations like this and a few other issues as already commented.